# In Android (using Java), how can I set the ring volume (to a specified number)?

Tags: java, android, settings, volume, vibration

So in my application, I have a seekbar that allows the user to set the ringer volume (0 - 100). I can't seem to find a way to set the ringer volume to a specified number. I looked through the [AudioManager](http://d.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) class but it tells me to either set ringermode to normal/silent/vibrate. That is **NOT** what I want. I want the volume to be a ***specific number***. Here's an example of what I'm looking for:

```
private void setRinger (int volume) // volume = 0 - 100
{
    setRingVolume (volume); // Whenever a person gets a call/sms/warning/anything etc., it should be this volume.
}
```

Is this possible in Android? If so, how? Can you give me an example of how I can do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look up the AudioManager ([documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html)). It should have everything you need, including `setVibrateSetting`, `setRingerMode`, `setStreamVolume`. All those settings are separate from each other.

Comment: Hi, please check my edited post. I don't think you understood what I was looking for the first time.

Comment: I don't think you understood my answer :) What about `setStreamVolume` doesn't solve the problem?

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes it does! Thank you very much! Sorry for the misunderstanding, I kept looking at setRingerMode.

Comment: Ha, in your defense, that function name is VERY cryptic, to say the least. I had to look twice myself. I hope this does the trick for you! Good luck!