# Force iOS, Android And/Or Blackberry to Ring on Silent

Tags: android, ios, titanium, blackberry-10, titanium-modules

I work for a company that can send out public safety messages. I unfortunately can't give code samples or explain exactly how it works, so this is more of a "is this possible" type question.

In the case of our app, it is essential to get public safety messages out to people subscribed regardless of time or day. This includes the night, when people turn their phone on silent. If there is a gas explosion and an area needs to be evacuated immediately, or if there is a freak storm and people need to seek shelter, we want to be able to wake them up and get them out of the area and into safety. One incident that keeps coming up in discussion was that train explosion in Lac Megantic, Quebec this past summer. Had the police sent out a message that told everybody in the area to evacuate, some people's lives may have been spared.

So, is there a way to force an iOS, an Android or a Blackberry device to ring when on silent? We are building the the iOS and Android apps in Titanium Studios, with Blackberry being built natively.

I have a feeling that Android is yes and iOS is no, but I'm just starting to get into app development so I really have no idea.

Thank you!

Comment: You're asking three questions. It's doubtful that you will get three answers from one person, so this won't be a very useful reference question later on. As far as Android goes, Titanium is just a poor choice for this sort of app, because you'd really want a background service listening to push notifications. I'd expect this to be an equally poor choice on iOS as well.

Comment: Judging from the iOS questions posted by users of Titanium and other cross platform frameworks,  it's a poor choice for iOS too.  Especially for any kind of app which is not a vanilla web-view consuming a web service.  
I concur with 323go that you want push notifications.  The way these operate is highly platform specific and furthermore requires a substantial amount of back-end support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers to these questions exist elsewhere on SO, however they are not applied directly to Titanium. You will have to adapt these for `Titanium`.

- [iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859402/ios-change-device-volume)
- [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295333/in-android-using-java-how-can-i-set-the-ring-volume-to-a-specified-number)

This one is adapted from an Android port, but should help you out:

- [Blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542910/cannot-set-volume-on-blackberry-playbook)

Comment: Perfect! I just wanted to know if it was possible, and it looks like it is. Thanks a lot!